# How can I know when my screen was locked last time?

Tags: log, lock-screen, idle

Exist a log where I can look for that information? I want to know last days when my PC automatically locked the screen because was idle.

Comment: For unlocked time I did: `cat screen /var/log/auth.log | grep unlock` - no sudo necessary.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can find the unlock screen events using the following command:

```
grep screen /var/log/auth.log*
```

But there is not so simple to find the lock screen events because by default doesn't exist any log for these events (as far as I know).

Anyway, you can run the following command for logging the lock screen events:

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='org.gnome.ScreenSaver'" | ( while true; do read X; if echo "$X" | grep "boolean true" &> /dev/null; then  echo "Screen locked on $(date)" > $HOME/lock_screen.log; fi; done )
```

in `~/lock_screen.log` file.

If you like the above command, then use it in a script and make the script to run automatically at startup.

References:

- [Logging lock-screen events](https://superuser.com/q/662974/221259)
- [Run script on screen lock/unlock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/28181/37944)

Comment: doesn't seem to work on ubuntu 17.04. The ouput of `dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6'"` is `signal time=1497336035.520628 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.140 serial=2 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameAcquired
   string ":1.140"
signal time=1497336035.520706 sender=org.freedesktop.DBus -> destination=:1.140 serial=4 path=/org/freedesktop/DBus; interface=org.freedesktop.DBus; member=NameLost
   string ":1.140"`, then nothing when I lock or unlock

Answer (score 2):

FWIW: what works for me on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS with Unity, is monitoring DBUS with the following command:

```
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='com.canonical.Unity.Session'"
```

...and then monitoring for "Locked" and "Unlocked" events. Example output:

> signal time=1525269138.855107 sender=:1.51 -> destination=(null destination) serial=86735 path=/com/canonical/Unity/Session; interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session; member=LockRequested
>
> signal time=1525269139.409261 sender=:1.51 -> destination=(null destination) serial=86892 path=/com/canonical/Unity/Session; interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session; member=Locked
>
> signal time=1525269151.238899 sender=:1.51 -> destination=(null destination) serial=86937 path=/com/canonical/Unity/Session; interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session; member=UnlockRequested
>
> signal time=1525269151.791874 sender=:1.51 -> destination=(null destination) serial=86938 path=/com/canonical/Unity/Session; interface=com.canonical.Unity.Session; member=Unlocked

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use in Ubuntu 16.04. It logs to the system syslog.

Add to your home folder, mark as executable, and then use `gnome-session-properties` to configure it to run on session startup.

```
#!/bin/bash

exit_report(){
logger "$(date) Lockscreen Monitoring Terminated."
}
trap "exit_report; exit;" 0

lockmon() {
adddate() {
    while IFS= read -r line; do
      echo $line | grep string | grep '"start"' -q
      if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        logger "$(date) Screen locked"
      fi
      echo $line | grep string | grep '"stop"' -q
      if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
        logger "$(date) Screen unlocked"
      fi
    done
}
logger "$(date) Lockscreen Monitoring Started."
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Instance'" | adddate
}

lockmon
```

*Based on a [similar answer for Fedora systems](https://superuser.com/questions/662974/logging-lock-screen-events).*