# Script to check system is locked or not at certain time

Tags: 14.04, bash, process

I want to write a script to check whether system is locked or not at certain time.

So can anyone tell me what would be the condition to verify that system is locked or not ?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: check here -- http://askubuntu.com/questions/435069/how-can-i-know-when-my-screen-was-locked-last-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for ubuntu 14.04

```
#!/bin/bash
dbus-monitor --session "type='signal',interface='com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6'" | \
(
  while true; do
    read X
    if echo $X | grep "desktop-lock" &> /dev/null; then
      SCREEN_LOCKED;
    elif echo $X | grep "desktop-unlock" &> /dev/null; then
      SCREEN_UNLOCKED;
    fi
  done
)
```

This script will print the lock screen activity.

Reference: [run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28181/run-script-on-screen-lock-unlock)