# How to check unlock history in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, security, user-management, unlock

I am running on a laptop with Ubuntu 18.04.
Please guide me how to check the history of when my PC was unlocked.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/435069/how-can-i-know-when-my-screen-was-locked-last-time

Comment: @Steve Are you sure that the accepted answer worked? Is it *really* what you looking for?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>t</kbd> and type `history`.

This will provide a list of events on your computer.

In terminal Type `man history`

and it will give a list of the options for history usage.

Comment: Bash history != login history

Comment: what is even more weird: it got accepted. why?